# Looking for efficient X3D file reader component or Java code snippet

Tags: java, dom, x3d

The legacy java app is reading CAD X3D files & missing geometric data. I have searched online and looking for "*hands-on expert advice/recommendations*" for Component or Java code snippets to read X3D files.

Thanks

**Sample code:**

```
public Element loadGraphicsFile(File graphicsFile) throws Exception {
    Element sceneRoot = null;   
    InputStream stream = null;

    try {
        String fileName = graphicsFile.getName();
        if(fileName.endsWith(".gz") || fileName.endsWith(".x3dz")) {
            stream = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(graphicsFile));
        } 
        else {
            stream = new FileInputStream(graphicsFile);
        }

        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
        Document fileDocument = builder.build(stream);

        Element docRoot = fileDocument.getRootElement();    // <X3D/>
        Element topSceneRoot = docRoot.getChild("Scene");   // <Scene>
        sceneRoot = topSceneRoot.getChild("Transform");     // <Transform>
        Element tempRoot = sceneRoot.getChild("Transform"); // Nested <Transform>
        if(tempRoot != null) {  //some (CATIA?) have 2nd transform level
            sceneRoot = tempRoot;   
        } finally {
            if(stream != null) stream.close();
        }

        return sceneRoot;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code will only work for X3D files organized to a particular patterns,

Comment: More general X3D tools in Java are X3D-Edit https://savage.nps.edu/X3D-Edit/ and Xj3D  https://sourceforge.net/projects/xj3d/

Comment: If you are interested in extracting geometric data from an X3D file, suggest you post details about that problem, and we can suggest how to do it with standard XML processing tools available in Java

Comment: Hello Vincent & thank you for the references, I'll check them out ASAP. I already do it with standard XML processing tools in my application & looking for an alternative to compare & validate results efficiently. Have a great weekend.

Comment: You can also use X3D Java Scene Access Interface Library (X3DJSAIL) which is a strongly typed POJO library for X3D. Open source, jars published.  Includes validation and a number of other options. http://www.web3d.org/specifications/java/X3DJSAIL.html